# Cannot invoke "Append" with Argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working with extensions in Swift, and have created an extension for String as follows:

```
 extension String
{
func reverse() -> String
{
    let chars = Array(arrayLiteral: self).reverse()
    var reversed = ""
    for char in chars
    {
        reversed.append(char)
    }

    return reversed
}
}

name = "Faisal Syed"
name.reverse()
```

on the line that says

```
reversed.append(char)
```

I get an error saying that I can't invoke "append" with an argument list of type String.

How do I work around this?

Comment: `let chars = characters.reverse()
`

Comment: or simply `var reverse: String { return String(characters.reverse()) }`

Comment: Ah that worked thank you so much